# How to enable-disable Notifications in settings app using sdk?

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, application-settings, apple-push-notifications

I want to use push notification in my app so first time it launches it will automatically ask for notification.So i want to enable-disable push notification settings for my app programmatically.Note-I do not want to unregistered my app just disable Alert,badge,Sound for my app in settings app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this via the SDK. You'll have to inform the user that your app requires push notifications turned on, and then they'll have to go to Settings and turn it on themselves.

Apps have no control over the phone's settings, only its own.